# Dynamic targets for Prometheus in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

In my docker setup, I maintain `targets.json` file which is dynamically updated with targets to probe. The file starts empty but is appended with targets during some use case.

**sample targets.json**

```
[
  {
    "targets": [
      "x.x.x.x"
    ],
    "labels": {
      "app": "testApp1"
    }
  },
  {
    "targets": [
      "x.x.x.x"
    ],
    "labels": {
      "app": "testApp2"
    }
  }
]
```

This file is then provided to prometheus configuration as `file_sd_configs`. Everything works fine, targets get added to targets.json file due to some event in application and prometheus starts monitoring along with blackbox for health checks.

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'test-run'
    metrics_path: /probe
    params:
      module: [icmp]
    file_sd_configs:
      - files:
        - targets.json
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        target_label: __param_target
      - source_labels: [__param_target]
        target_label: instance
      - target_label: __address__
        replacement: blackbox:9115
```

Inside my node.js application I am able to append data to targets.json file, **but** now I trying to replicate this in Kubernetes on minikube. I tried adding in ConfigMap as following and it works, but I dont want to populate targets in configuration, but rather maintain a json file.

Can this be done using Persistent Volumes? The pod running Prometheus will always read the targets file and pod running application will write to targets file.

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: prometheus-cm
data:
  targets.json: |-
    [
      {
        "targets": [
          "x.x.x.x"
        ],
        "labels": {
          "app": "testApp1"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Simply, what strategy in Kubernetes is recommended to so that one pod can read a json file and another pod can write to that file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to achieve your goal you need to use [PVC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/):

> A **PersistentVolume (PV)** is a piece of storage in the cluster that has
> been provisioned by an administrator. It is a resource in the cluster
> just like a node is a cluster resource. PVs are volume plugins like
> Volumes, but have a lifecycle independent of any individual pod that
> uses the PV. This API object captures the details of the
> implementation of the storage, be that NFS, iSCSI, or a
> cloud-provider-specific storage system.
>
> A **PersistentVolumeClaim (PVC)** is a request for storage by a user. It
> is similar to a pod. Pods consume node resources and PVCs consume PV
> resources. Pods can request specific levels of resources (CPU and
> Memory). Claims can request specific size and access modes (e.g., can
> be mounted once read/write or many times read-only).

The json file needs to be persisted if one pod has to write to it and another one to read it. There is an [official guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/) describing that concept in steps:

- Create a `PersistentVolume`
- Create a `PersistentVolumeClaim`
- Create a `Pod` that uses your `PersistentVolumeClaim` as a volume

I also recommend reading this: [Create ReadWriteMany PersistentVolumeClaims on your Kubernetes Cluster](https://medium.com/asl19-developers/create-readwritemany-persistentvolumeclaims-on-your-kubernetes-cluster-3a8db51f98e3) as a supplement.

Comment: The links have been helpful and I am able to work with dynamic targets, thanks!